# 404 error when i try open my app

Tags: facebook, http-status-code-404

I try to make simple "hello world" app for facebook. But when i try to enter my app it says 404 error. 
app link: https://apps.facebook.com/caponekuponfb/

I cant upload my config screen so i will re-write it:

---

```
## Basic information ##
App Display Name: Kupony Capone
App Namespace: caponekuponfb
Contact Email: address@address
App Domain: blank
Category: None
Hosting URL: You have not generated a URL through one of our partners (Get one)

## App on Facebook ##
Canvas URL: http://www.adamlakomy.pl/
Secure Canvas URL: https://ssl.1and1.pl/adamlakomy.pl/
Canvas Page: http://apps.facebook.com/caponekuponfb

## Facebook Tab ##
Page Tab Name: Kupon zniżkowy w Capone
Page Tab URL: http://www.adamlakomy.pl/kupon.html
Secure Page Tab URL: https://ssl.1and1.pl/adamlakomy.pl/kupon.html
Page Tab Edit URL: blank

Rest is blank/default
```

Where problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.adamlakomy.pl/ is also answering with 404 error. When you open http://apps.facebook.com/caponekuponfb you're forwarded to http://www.adamlakomy.pl/ und there is the 404 error

Comment: I've edited links to: http://www.adamlakomy.pl/facebook/capone/kupon.html and https://ssl.1and1.pl/adamlakomy.pl/facebook/capone/kupon.html both are ok when I enter from links above but still FB shows 4oh4

Comment: What is your Canvas URL in the settings of your app? I was able to open your links but your app still shows the 404 error. Your canvas url (both non secure and secure) should look like this http://yoursite.pl/canvasfolder/ and there should be index.html or index.php inside. So for example your canvas url should be http://adamlakomy.pl/facebook/capone/, then rename kupone.html to index.html and all should be ok

Comment: i got typo in canvas URL. Now everything works perfectly! Thanks alot.